# Day convolution on the category of copresheaves on the opposite of a monoidal closed category

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

When $\mathcal{C}$ is symmetric monoidal closed, the Day convolution gives a symmetric monoidal closed structure to the category $[\mathcal{C},\mathbf{Set}]$.

Suppose that instead, it is $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}$ that is symmetric monoidal closed. Hence, $[\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}},\mathbf{Set}]$ is monoidal closed with the Day tensor product. My question is, can I use the Day convolution to say something about $[\mathcal{C},\mathbf{Set}]$? E.g., is it true that the opposite of it, $[\mathcal{C},\mathbf{Set}]^{\text{op}}$ is symmetric monoidal closed?

I guess this should be a matter of playing around with the definitions, but unfortunately I am not experienced enough to do this myself.

Comment: You are asking two different questions. Please ask them in two different posts, linking one to the other if you want.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry. I have changed the question, I hope this is ok now...

Comment: Yes, it's ok. Don't worry, it's not a big deal :)

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathcal{C}$ is monoidal then $\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}$ is monoidal. $[\mathcal{C}^{\mathrm{opop}},\mathsf{Set}] = [\mathcal{C},\mathsf{Set}]$ is monoidal closed under Day convolution, i.e. $[\mathcal{C},\mathsf{Set}]^\mathrm{op}$ is co-closed under Day convolution in the opposite category... if you want to be really explicit, then 
$$\begin{align}
X \otimes Y(c) &= 
\int^{c_1,c_2 \in \mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}} \mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}(c,c_1 \otimes  c_1) \times X(c_1) \times Y(c_2) \\
&= \int^{c_1,c_2 \in \mathcal{C}} \mathcal{C}(c_1\otimes c_2,c) \times X(c_1) \times Y(c_2)
\end{align}
$$

Did you have something else in mind?